# Write a Chat Ping Counter

Tags: code-golf, string, counting

Your task is to write a program, that given a list of chat messages, count how many times each person gets pinged, so I can know how popular everyone is.  But, since I have to do it surreptitiously, I need it to be as small as possible so I can hide the code.

## Specs

- The input comes in a list of 2-tuples, with each item being of the form `("username", "message")`.
- A ping to another user is defined as an `@` followed by 3 or more letters that unambiguously refers to that user.
- However, you also have to consider replies, which have to start with `:messageid` followed by a space.
- Assume the first message has id `0` and proceed sequentially.
- Output each user and say how many times each one got pinged.
- The output can be in any order/reasonable format.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in **bytes** wins!

## Test Cases

```
[["AlexA.", "I am wrong"], ["Quartatoes", "@Alex you are very wrong"], ["AlexA.", ":1 I am only slightly wrong"]]
AlexA.: 1
Quartatoes: 1

[["Doorknob", "I have never eaten an avocad."], ["AquaTart", ":0 I will ship you an avocad"], ["AlexA.", ":0 this is shocking"]]
Doorknob: 2
AquaTart: 0
AlexA.: 0

[["Geobits", "I like causing sadness through downvotes."], ["Flawr", "I want to put random message ids in my chat messages :0 askjdaskdj"]]
Geobits: 0
Flawr: 0

[["Downgoat", "goatigfs.com/goatgif"], ["Downotherthing", "@Downgoat cool gifs"], ["Dennis", "@Down cool gifs this is an ambiguous ping"]]
Downgoat: 1
Downotherthing: 0
Dennis: 0
```

Comment: I like how `:0` doubles as a surprised emoticon.

Comment: *"I like causing sadness through downvotes."* You know there's only one proper way I can respond to that, right? ;)

Comment: Can there be multiple pings in each message? If so, can they be of different "types" (reply *and* one or more pings)? And if so, could you add some test cases involving this?

Comment: @Doorknob yes to all of these questions, I will add cases.

Comment: @Maltysen Can the username contain spaces? And would `username message\nusername message` be a valid way to take input?

Comment: At what point are we stopping with the "Alex is wrong" jokes?

Comment: Can replies contain mentions e.g. `:0 @someone`?

Comment: Can I take the input as an array of objects, such as `[{user: "name", msg: "words"}, {...}]`?

Comment: Can a reply be out of range (e.g. first message starting with `:3`) or a ping not satisfying any user in the room (e.g. `@zzz`)?

Comment: The final example seems invalid - `@Down` does not unambiguously refer to any user.

Comment: @isaacg That's the idea. Per the 2nd spec, they should only count towards a user if it referes to them unambiguously. Because `@Down` could refer to two people, it should be ignored.

Comment: @Mwr247 I get it - I thought that that spec meant that such ambiguous pings couldn't appear in the input, by rereading things I see that you're right.

Comment: Can a pinged user not yet have posted a message when he's pinged? e.g. is `[["Doorknob","@Alex is wrong"],["Alex","I am only slightly wrong"]]` valid input?

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>245</s> 210 bytes

```js
a=>(p={},a.map(b=>p[b[0]]=0),(a.map(b=>b[1].match(/@[a-z]{3,}|^:\d+/gi)||[]).map(c=>c.map(d=>(z=(d[0]=='@'?(y=Object.keys(p).filter(e=>e.startsWith(d.slice(1)))).length<2?y:0:a[d.slice(1)[0]]))&&p[z[0]]++))),p)
```

Uses an object to create a unique list of names alongside pings. Then it looks through the messages for matches to either ping condition. If a name, it looks through the list of names to find if there is only one match, and then increments. If a reply, it simply references that index in the message array and pulls the name to be incremented. Finally, it returns the object.

Comment: Surely using an object is shorter. If it isn't I don't think you need to return the Map as an array

Comment: @Downgoat But `Map` is more fun right? Na, I originally overestimated how much extra it would take to reference an object, thinking I would have to a separate array for names, but you're right that it is much shorter this way.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 227 Bytes

```
foreach($_GET[a]as $c){$r[]=&$n[$c[0]]??$n[$c[0]]=0;preg_match("#^(:(\d+)|@(\w+))#",$c[1],$m);$m[2]==""?!$m[3]?:count($a=preg_grep("#^{$m[3]}#",array_keys($n)))>1?:$n[end($a)]++:$r[$m[2]]++;}foreach(($n)as$k=>$v)echo"$k: $v\n";
```